# Does a saturated inductor radiate more?

Tags: inductor, emc, saturation

Background:

I am using a shielded inductor in a switching power supply, and am investigating an EMI issue.

My hypothesis is that since the inductor is saturated, the magnetic field is no longer contained in the ferrite core, and the inductor becomes equivalent to an air core inductor. I know that air core inductors radiate their magnetic field much more than ferrite core inductors.

Question:

Once a ferrite core inductor saturates, does its magnetic field get radiated significantly more?

Comment: "Radiated" is a bit strange word for it, but your core will capture fewer and fewer field lines the deeper you put it into saturation. Saturate it fully and your field lines will look like a normal air core.

Comment: @winny this is the answer to my question.

Comment: +1 for @winny, but why does it saturate? In a DC-DC you really want to avoid that...

Comment: Listen to what @peufeu says, don't saturate your inductor. It's highly unlikely it's the source of your EMI problem.

Comment: If it's under-sized and does saturate, maybe you get current spiking wildly until the regulator manages to turn off the MOSFET, on every cycle... loss of efficiency and worse di/dt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the core is saturated, it doesn't look like a magnetic core anymore when you try to increate the magnetic field.  The inductor becomes essentially air-core for any additional current.

While over-saturating a shielded inductor will cause the magnetic field to leak outside the shield more, this shouldn't cause much radiation by itself.  More likely the sudden decrease in inductance causes large current spikes somewhere.  These can cause radiation, depending on how they are routed, and therefore how much they act as antennas.

Answer (score 0):

As inductor saturates, the rate of change of magnetic flux also decreases significantly, which in turns produces less EM radiation [you need changing flux for EM propagation]. Conversely, as the indcutor saturates, the current through it jumps high during saturation period in each cycle. That jump in current might produce EM radiation if the circuit conductor/wire acts as good antenna.

Comment: Your answer doean't seem to add anything new compared to the already selected answer. Is there something else to add? Welcome to the site.